# How to link Github account to another system account using Oauth

Tags: github, oauth, authorization, token

I am trying to use Github Oauth App for authorization purpose. No Authentication, no sign in with github.

I would like a user (having an account on my app) to link their GitHub account to my app's account. I understand the github web flow. Let the user authorize Oauth app for the first time. Get the authorization code. Fetch an access token using the code. And use that token to do git operations on user's behalf.

Now the thing I am unsure about is, what if the user logs out of my app and logs back in again?

Not a good practise to ask them to link accounts for each login.

Should I automatically do the Oauth flow again and generate a new access token for each login? If that is, why does Github Oauth App have an access token that won't expire? And why does Oauth app store multiple tokens for the same user, same scope? Why not remove the previous token and store the new one only? Because of this move by Github, I believe this is not the correct way to go. I don't know.

Or, should I store their initial token in the database, and use the same token forever? Is that a good practise? And if that is, how do I verify the scopes initially defined for that token is still the same? I couldn't understand this bit, reading through the Github documentation.

I hope I was clear enough. I couldn't understand this account linking thing.